# Climb a step to a prime

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, primes

The title of Numberphile's newest video, [13532385396179](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IMAUm2WY70), is a fixed point of the following function \$f\$ on the positive integers:

> Let \$n\$ be a positive integer. Write the prime factorization in the usual way, e.g. \$60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\$, in which the primes are written in increasing order, and exponents of 1 are omitted. Then bring exponents down to the line and omit all multiplication signs, obtaining a number \$f(n)\$. [...] for example, \$f(60) = f(2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5) = 2235\$.

(The above definition is taken from Problem 5 of [Five $1,000 Problems - John H. Conway](https://oeis.org/A248380/a248380.pdf))

Note that \$f(13532385396179) = f(13 \cdot 53^2 \cdot 3853 \cdot 96179) = 13532385396179\$.

### Task

Take a positive composite integer \$n\$ as input, and output \$f(n)\$.

### Another example

\$48 = 2^4 \cdot 3\$, so \$f (48) = 243\$.

### Testcases

More testcases are available [here](https://pastebin.com/VKnL9eFF).

```
   4 -> 22
   6 -> 23
   8 -> 23
  48 -> 243
  52 -> 2213
  60 -> 2235
 999 -> 3337
9999 -> 3211101
```

Comment: +1 I'm still astonished that someone managed to find 13532385396179 as a disproof of the conjecture.  I guess the $1000 prize would go some way to pay for the electricity used! :)

Comment: Without following the link it wasn't clear that the conjecture is that repeated applications of *f(n)* will always reach a prime (and of course *f(p) = p* if *p* is prime). 13532385396179 disproves the conjecture because it's both composite and a fixed opint.

Answer (score 16):

## Python, <s>166</s> <s>162</s> 159 bytes

You guys are much better. This is what I used! (the algorithm that solved it calls this)

```python
from primefac import*
def c(n):
 x=factorint(n)
 a=''
 for i in range(len(x)):
  l=min(x.keys())
  a+=str(l)
  if x[l]>1:a+=str(x[l])
  x.pop(l)
 return int(a)
```

Comment: 1. Please include the language and number of bytes. 2. Please attempt to golf down your program (reduce the number of bytes) by for example using single-letter variables. 3. Please include the import statements (`factorint` is obviously not a built-in function).

Comment: Why did someone downvote a newcomer instead of helping him improve his answer as @LeakyNun did? :(

Comment: Sorry- that really is what I used (I found the number).  I just thought the crummy code would be funny. You can take it down.

Comment: Welcome on the site. It's really nice to have you sharing with us your solution. (for people who don't know, Jim Davis is the one who solved this problem in the first place). However, answers to challenges need to follow some rules. If you just follow the suggestions from @LeakyNun, then you answer will be valid. (maybe have a look at the other answers to see how they usually look like)

Comment: I edited in a golfed version. I do not know Python, so if I introduced syntax errors, please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Stephen!  I didn't mean to be rude and couldn't figure out how to delete the post.

Comment: Oh my God, I didn't expect Jim Davis himself to appear in this site, and to answer my challenge... I feel so honoured now...

Comment: @JimDavis No problem, honestly I think we were being rude. We have fairly high standards for what is "valid".

Comment: No, not at all.  I didn't bother to learn the syntax to post or anything.  All these little six bit programs look like magic!  And I appreciate you being nice to somebody who is a troll for all you know.

Comment: ehh, not a troll by the way.  My email address is on http://gladhoboexpress.blogspot.ca/2014/10/climb-to-prime.html ... I left the post up, nobody swamps you with email over math.

Comment: You can remove the space before the asterisk, the `0,` in range (`range(0, x) == range(x)`), that saves 3 bytes, together. If this is Python 2, you can also replace calls to `str` with repr notation, e.g. `` `l` ``, which would save you another 6 bytes :)

Comment: It's extremely cool that you've posted a program, but importing a non-standard module is stretching things a little. ;) OTOH, the really tiny answers on this site come from golfing languages that have all sorts of crazy functions built in...

Comment: Would `a=0` work to save a byte?

Comment: And by the way, it is against the policy of PPCG to edit a golf into another author's post, so feel free to rollback the edits if you wish.

Answer (score 10):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆFFḟ1V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5vbwx3zDcP@//9vCQQA)

#### Explanation

```
ÆF      Get prime factorisation of input as prime-exponent pairs.
  F     Flatten.
   ḟ1   Remove 1s.
     V  Effectively flattens the list into a single integer.
```

Comment: `V` = "concatenate to a single string and eval as Jelly"

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, hence "effectively".

Comment: @MartinEnder Any particular reason you don't use `Ḍ` (Convert from decimal to integer)?

Comment: @Christian Because the list might contain multi-digit integers.

Comment: @MartinEnder Ah, clever. I've used `FḌ` in the past - that's a good tip!

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ḋoọc;1xc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7vyHu3uTrQ0rkv//t7S0/B8FAA)

#### Explanation

```
Example input: 60

ḋ          Prime decomposition: [5,3,2,2]
 o         Order: [2,2,3,5]
  ọ        Occurences: [[2,2],[3,1],[5,1]]
   c       Concatenate: [2,2,3,1,5,1]
    ;1x    Execute 1s: [2,2,3,5]
       c   Concatenate: 2235
```

You can use `ℕ₂ˢ` (*select all integers greater than or equal to 2*) instead of `;1x`, which is probably more readable and more in the spirit of Brachylog.

Answer (score 7):

## [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 34 bytes

```
Row[Join@@FactorInteger@#/.1->""]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KL882is/M8/BwS0xuSS/yDOvJDU9tchBWV/PUNdOSSlW7X9AUWZeiYJDmoMlEPwHAA)

-2 bytes from @sanchez

Comment: `DeleteCases` is long, you can use `/.1->""` or `/.1->##&[]` (alternative form of `/.1->Nothing`

Comment: @user202729 All of those need a space in front of the `1` to prevent it from parsing as `... / (0.1)`.

Comment: You are right! fixed

Comment: Using `Join`, i.e. `Row[Join@@FactorInteger@#/.1->""]&` results in 34 bytes

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
limF:~1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T8nM9fNqs5Q939sXq2F1n8TLjMuCy4TCy5TIy4zAy5LS0sQtgQA)

#### Explanation

```
li  e# Read input and convert to integer.
mF  e# Get prime factorisation as prime-exponent pairs.
:~  e# Flatten.
1-  e# Remove 1s.
    e# Implicitly print a flattened representation of the list.
```

Comment: I would have used `e_` to flatten, since that's what it's there for, but it doesn't change the score.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hm yeah, I can never decide which one to use, but tend to go with `e_` for deep flatten only and use `:~` whenever it's just a single level.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
Òγʒ¬?gDië?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8KRzm09NOrTGPt0l8/Bq@///LYEAAA)

```
Ò          # Push list of prime factors with duplicates
 γ         # Break into chunks of consecutive elements
  ʒ        # For each
   ¬?      #   Print the first element
     gD    #   Push the length of this chunk twice
       ië  #   If not 1
         ? #     Print the length
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
Òγvy¬sgD≠×J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8KRzm8sqD60pTnd51Lng8HSv//9NLAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ò            # calculate prime factors with duplicates
 γ           # group consecutive equal elements
  vy         # for each group
    ¬        # get the head without popping
     sg      # push the length of the group
       D≠×   # repeat the length (length != 1) times
          J  # join
```

Comment: Fails for `48`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
smjk_>hddr8P
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smjk_%3Ehddr8P&input=9999&debug=0)

#### alternative, 12 bytes

```
smjk<_AdGr8P
```

[Try that!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smjk%3C_AdGr8P&input=9999&debug=0)

#### explanation

```
smjk_>hddr8P
           PQ  # prime factorization (already in correct order) of the implicit input: [3, 3, 11, 101]
         r8    # length encode: [[2, 3], [1, 11], [1, 101]]
 m             # map over the length encoded list (lambda variable: d)
     >hdd      # take the d[0] last elements of d (so only the last for d[0]==1 and all else)
    _          # reverse that list
  jk           # join into a string
s              # conatenate the list of strings
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
jksm_-d1r8P
```

[Try here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jksm_-d1r8P&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A6%0A8%0A48%0A52%0A60%0A999%0A9999&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 99 bytes

```python
n=input()
r=''
p=2
while~-n:
 e=0
 while n%p<1:e+=1;n/=p
 r+=str(p)*(e>0)+str(e)*(e>1);p+=1
print r
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCoMwDIDhe54iF7G1iK236eLbBFoYWcgqsstevVP/2we/fmt@y9yaUBHdq/Ng1PegNMORy4t/oyyATBHwNkqnz7RwoLTKRApogT7VnPrB8RZ9uMA3kl/1/ECtSEVr7XH2Bw)**

If inputs are restricted to be below `2147483659`, both `str(...)` may be replaced by `` `...` `` saving 6 bytes (this program will be **very** slow for numbers affected anyway!).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 11 bytes

```
o:_]D2<?O;J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f8/3yo@1sXIxt7f2uv/f0sgAAA)

#### Explanation

```
o:_]D2<?O;J
o           # Push prime factors with powers from input (Format [[prime,power],...]
 :          # For each...
  _          # Push current element
   ]         # flatten
    D        # Duplicate power
     2<? ;   # Is the power smaller than 2?
        O     # Delete top of stacks
          J  # Join
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 88 bytes

```php
for($i=2;1<$a=&$argn;)$a%$i?$i++:$a/=$i+!++$r[$i];foreach($r as$k=>$v)echo$k,$v<2?"":$v;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoMwFAX3nkLDU5QUpO7055uDSBcfsSYINaSQ66ehsxoYJriQjQ0uVJB4fljNBUX5fccenid6Ggh3/0gDpIW38FovkJGLNFojbvAvKschu@sRa/ni4hVpOHZ343ogmckqtSBRzj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 bytes

```
k ó¥ ®¯1 pZlÃc fÉ q
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ayDzpSCurzEgcFpsw2MgZskgcQ==&input=OTk5OQ==)

#### Explanation

```
 k ó¥  ®   ¯  1 pZlÃ c fÉ  q
Uk ó== mZ{Zs0,1 pZl} c f-1 q  // Ungolfed
                              // Implicit: U = input number
Uk                            // Break U into its prime factors.
   ó==                        // Group into runs of equal items.
       mZ{         }          // Map each item Z in this to
          Zs0,1               //   Z.slice(0, 1) (the array of the first item),
                pZl           //   with Z.length added at the end.
                              // This returns an array of prime-exponent pairs (Jelly's ÆF).
                     c        // Flatten.
                       f-1    // Filter to the items X where X - 1 is truthy (removes '1's).
                           q  // Join the resulting array into a single string.
                              // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
x=rle(pracma::factors(scan()));x$l[x$l<2]='';paste0(x$v,x$l,collapse='')
```

Requires the `pracma` package, which is not installed on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Adám

```apl
∊⍕¨1~⍨∊⍉2⌂pco⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM9DUh0PeqdemiFYd2j3hVgTqfRo56mguT8R31TQUr@p3GZcKVxmQGxBRCbgAhTI5CIAZCwtLSEkJYA)

```apl
∊⍕¨1~⍨∊⍉2⌂pco⎕
               ⎕      ⍝ Input
          2⌂pco        ⍝ Prime factors with exponents
        ⍉             ⍝ Transpose so the 1st column is factors, 2nd is exponents
       ∊               ⍝ Flatten
    1~⍨               ⍝ Remove 1
 ⍕¨                   ⍝ Convert each to a string
∊                      ⍝ Concatenate them together
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>206</s> 100 bytes

```c#
n=>{var r="";for(int d=1,c;++d<=n;){c=0;while(n%d<1){c++;n/=d;}r+=c>0?d+(c>1?c+"":""):"";}return r;}
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
using System;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, string> func = n =>
        {
            var r = "";
            for (int d = 1, c; ++d <= n;)
            {
                c = 0;
                while (n % d < 1)
                {
                    c++;
                    n /= d;
                }

                r += c > 0 ? d + (c > 1 ? c + "" : "") : "";
            }

            return r;
        };

        Console.WriteLine(func(4));
        Console.WriteLine(func(6));
        Console.WriteLine(func(8));
        Console.WriteLine(func(48));
        Console.WriteLine(func(52));
        Console.WriteLine(func(60));
        Console.WriteLine(func(999));
        Console.WriteLine(func(9999));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript - 91 bytes

```
(x,r='',i=1,n)=>{while(x>i++){for(n=0;x%i<1;n++)x/=i;r+=(n>0?i+'':'')+(n>1?n:'')}return r}
```

### Explanation

```
(x,r='',i=1,n)=>(          // input x is the number to process, r, i, n are default values only
    while(x>i++){          // iterate over i until x
        for(n=0;x%i<1;n++) // iterate over n until i is not a factor of x
            x/=i;          // factor i out of x
        r+=(n>0?i+'':'')   // append i to r if n > 0
            +(n>1?n:'')    // append n to r if n > 1
                           // i+'' prevents adding i and n before appending to r
    }
    return r               // return r by comma-operator and arrow function syntax
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 103 chars

Pretty straightforward solution.

```
n->{String r="";int d=2,c;while(n>1){c=0;while(n%d<1){c++;n/=d;}if(c>0)r+=d;if(c>1)r+=c;d++;}return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
private static Function<Integer, String> f = n->{
    String result = "";
    int divisor = 2, count;
    while (n>1) {
        count = 0;
        while (n % divisor < 1) {
            count++;
            n /= divisor;
        }
        if (count > 0) result += divisor;
        if (count > 1) result += count;
        divisor++;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY/BboMwDIbvfQoLaRJRUgZVVxWy0CdYLztWPWRJmNJRg0LoNFVc9wB7xL0ICy072JLt3/78n@RFLpvW4El/jKqWXQcv0iJcFwAWvXGVVAb2Uwnw6p3Fd6jiMAEkPDSHRUidl94q2AOCGHFZXmehE1HEq8bd9FqsmOJYZtxRocp0p8psp6gudBFFTFNKJqUSKccH/ZxxfBSaKEq5M753CI4PI59obf9WB9oMvTRWwzm8HN@hhyNIcn/3n2yhADSfk5/D8bpmG7Zl6y17WrFNyvI8nyIfyG0nmPzqvDknTe@TNhz0NcaWRvD7/QMRxSSYJ7PzYfwD "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 69 bytes

```matlab
@(a)printf('%d',(f=[[~,c]=hist(b=factor(a),d=unique(b));d](:))(f~=1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco5DoAgEADA1xh2EwptLDSb@A9CsVyRBpTD0q@jU0@2jR8/xgGMV4mpBRCTExICKfVKq@mMtYGhwLbl8i/pqKd4dw8GcXcaNkQILy2Ig1OFdcbxAQ)

Ended up being quite long, but this will generate the desired output.

Essentially we use the histogram function to count the number of occurrences of the unique values in the prime factorisation of the input value.

- The result of the `factor()` function gives the prime factors in ascending order
- we then find `unique()` values in that array
- `hist()` returns the number of occurrences

Once we have the two arrays (one for unique factors, one for counts), we concatenate the arrays vertically (one on top of the other), and then flatten. This interleaves the factors with counts.

Finally we display the result as a string ensuring to skip any 1's in the final array. The only time 1's can appear is if the count was 1 because 1 will never be a prime factor. This elimination is done before converting to a string so it won't affect things like the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 + 7 bytes

Requires the flag `-rprime`.

```ruby
->n{(n.prime_division.flatten-[1]).join.to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiNPr6AoMzc1PiWzLLM4Mz9PLy0nsaQkNU832jBWUy8rPzNPryQ/PrP2f4FCWrQlEMQq2NoqGBsZGhoaGHJBBSFixsbm////yy8oARpT/F@3CGwwAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 16 bytes

```
V{PQpNK/PQNItKpK
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%7BPQpNK%2FPQNItKpK&input=18&debug=0)

Another solution:

```
sm`d-.nm(d/PQd){PQ1
```

Comment: One can replace `FN` by `V`.

Comment: Also, `r8` (run-length encoding) seems to be useful.